# Place PHP in a DIV Using JQUERY

Tags: php, mysql, class, html

I would like to place some php code within a div with the class called "pickme" using jquery.

So basically, Jquery goes through the DOM and finds every div with the class "pickme" and places a little php code in that div.

Any suggestions or codes used to perform this?

Comment: *places a little php code in that div* - Sorry, but PHP is executed on a server, not in the client. This is only relevant when making a request from a server (which may include HTML as a response).

Comment: you are probably talking about AJAX..

Comment: opposite of your question is quiet relevant i.e placing javascript (jquery) code inside div using php .

Comment: quite true - I am just trying to figure out how all these CMS's have "place this class in your div tags to edit."  I thought maybe there was some way I can call something to grab all of the divs with a certain class and place some code to allow someone to edit the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could load the php page into the div with the jquery .load() function. That will call the php, but if you need to alter the pages contents based on that php, you will need to make that php page use jquery to make those changes (outside of the div).

`$('#div').load('myPage.php');`

myPage.php will load server-side, then display, giving you the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: I do like this, I may look into this a bit more.  I have use this before, but I can't remember if the page expands with the div or if it works more like an iframe.  It's been a while since I've done this.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. If the div doesn't have a set height, then it should expand with the content.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up server side and client side concepts.
The php won't execute at this point.
Placing php code in a div with jquery will not cause the php to execute for php is a server side language. javascript executes on the client.

You will need to use ajax to make page fragment updates. Look at [ajax() for jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or even [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: hmm..looks like I need to freshen up on some javascript.  All I really want to do is place <? include_once('url'); ?> in the <div>.

Comment: Yes javascript is client side, the php won't execute on the client.